# Swift: why does "performSegueWithIdentifier" happen twice?

Tags: swift, uibutton, segue

In my app I have the following storyboard fragment:

[image]

and from the pink button I have added a show segue called "toFishPic" to the UIViewController at the rigth. This is the swift code linked to the pink button:

```
@IBAction func toFishPhoto(sender: UIButton) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFishPic", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but when the pink button is tapped the UIViewConroller at the right (the one with the big UIImageView) is loaded twice as if there was one identical after it. Why does this happen?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this asynchronously? Get rid of the dispatch_async and just call performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: Because I've always made it like that in my previous ios app project and it worked. I thought it was the right way...

Comment: Not needed at all, try it without.

Comment: I have just tried with simply `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFishPic", sender: self)` but I get the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are linked pink button to PhotoViewController directly instead ActionFishViewController to PhotoViewController. If you gonna use performSegueWithIdentifier, don't link directly and reconnect between controllers.

Try to dont call self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFishPic", sender: self) (//) and check if you can push to PhotoViewController. If it`s works means you linked button directly to PhotoViewController.

Comment: Yes, I had linked the pink button with PhotoViewController... It seemed I could not link ActionFishViewControllwe with PhotoViewController but that I was supposed to link the button. Omg...I'm making a lot of confusion. I'm gonna tried what you've suggested. Thanks

Comment: That was right pal! I had made a mistake by linking the pink button to the Photo View Controller. Instead I was supposed to link the two view controllers as you said. Thank you!